# While using Github Actions, I'm facing "Permission denied error"

Tags: github-actions

I'm working with Github actions lately and facing trouble while importing .p12 certificate to **build.keychain** and getting error as follows:

```
/Users/runner/work/_temp/47c4b40a-b302-4da8-a26c-562eaae4c0ee.sh: line 1: ./provisioning/import_provisioning.sh: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

After struggling for many hours I even tried to run this script manually on my terminal and everything seems to be working fine! I rechecked whether my passwords are wrong or whether i'm not able to access it or not! But i think i able to access my github secret properly, Any Idea why this may happening!

Here is my shell script file
**import_provisioning.sh**

```sh
gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase="$PROVISIONING_PASSWORD" --output provisioning/AppStoreCertificates.p12 provisioning/AppStoreCertificates.p12.gpg
gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase="$PROVISIONING_PASSWORD" --output provisioning/demo.mobileprovision provisioning/demo.mobileprovision.gpg

mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

echo "List profiles"
ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
echo "Move profiles"
cp provisioning/*.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
echo "List profiles"
ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

security create-keychain -p "" build.keychain
security import provisioning/AppStoreCertificates.p12 -t agg -k ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain -P "$PROVISIONING_PASSWORD" -A

security list-keychains -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security default-keychain -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
```

And just in case you're not getting it properly you can check github repo for reference https://github.com/dheerajghub/GithubPipeline/blob/master/provisioning/import_provisioning.sh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found out that the problem was in the file permission so i set file permission and everything thing seems to be working fine!

```
git update-index --chmod=+x provisioning/import_provisioning.sh
git commit -m "Changing file permissions"
```

Comment: Something I was stuck on for a while, when using Ubuntu or WSL2 you might need to **add `sudo` to the command**. Else the `update-index` silently fails.